# What are the criteria for our site to get out of beta?

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation, beta

Our site has been in beta for many years now. What are the criteria for a site to get out of beta?

- We have 16,000 visitors daily.
- We have a solid number of users 10,000+.
- Answered questions are above 90%

The number of questions a day is a little low at 3.7 a day but this might reflect that people find the answers without asking.

Comment: [A related recent post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/369802): Writing is struggling with the same problem of not meeting 10 questions per day. The answer there is discussing a proposal for changing the entire graduation system.

Comment: I will get back to this, @trondhansen, apologies for the delay.

Comment: it is okay take your time,i have seen this exact question on other beta sites too in the comments but no good answer yet as i can find.

Comment: Most of the questions will probably be repeat questions, unlike programming with billions of permutations, there's only so much you can ask about a pet, so it makes sense that the views to question ratio will be high